# Add handler for the gRPC server in Golang

Tags: go, grpc, amazon-kinesis

I have the following `server/server.go` definition for my `gRPC` server:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"

    "github.com/golang/glog"
    pb "github.com/go-grpc-tutorial/pb"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "net"
)

// Implements of EchoServiceServer

type echoServer struct{}

func newEchoServer() pb.EchoServiceServer {
    return new(echoServer)
}

func (s *echoServer) Echo(ctx context.Context, msg *pb.Message) (*pb.Message, error) {
    glog.Info(msg)
    return msg, nil
}

func Run() error {
    listen, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":50051")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    server := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterEchoServiceServer(server, newEchoServer())
    server.Serve(listen)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    defer glog.Flush()

    if err := Run(); err != nil {
        glog.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

I want the server to listen from a `Kinesis` stream, so whenever a message is posted to the `Kinesis` stream, it will consume that message and send it to the `Echo()` method.
So, I'm envisioning something like:

```
func handleKinesis(s *echoServer) error {
    // wait until a message is published to the kinesis stream
    records, err := readFromKinesis() // not implemented here
    if err != nil {
      return err
    }
    for _, record := records {
       message := string(record.Data)
       _, _ = s.Echo(context.Background(), &pb.Message{msg: message})
    }
}
```

And the `handleKinesis` would run in the background, just listening for new `Kinesis` messages, and then call the `echoServer` to process that message.
How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Are you intending on having your grpc functions called via grpc?  Or only via your kinesis consumer?

Comment: @sberry only via the kinesis consumer. I'm studying here what to do, but the idea is the consumer will call the `grpc` functions. Another idea is to implement one server that will consume from the different streams, and use the grpc client to call the corresponding server. What are your thoughts on those ideas?

Comment: Why have a grpc server at all then?  You are going to be calling a function over tcp/http2 instead in process.

Comment: True. How would you implement the consumer inside the server then?

Comment: @sberry for example, I can use a consumer such as https://github.com/harlow/kinesis-consumer ... how am I going to pass the consumed record to the server for processing?